# Imagine shop, there are $k$ different cashiers and $n$ different buyers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different distributions can there be if order in queue on cashiers matters?

Well, It is pretty easy to answer this question if we just find distribution. For each buyer we can choose one of k cashiers where he can be. Hence the answer would be $k^n$. But what happens if we try to consider the order in queue?

Comment: What do you mean by 'order in queue'? Is it one queue or k queues? Can you give an example of a scenario that you are looking for answer?

Comment: Line all the customers up in a single line in $n!$ ways.  Now we have to split them up into $k$ (possibly) empty groups and give the first group to the first cashier, the second to the second, and so on, so the question becomes, how many ways are there to split the line into $k$ groups?

Comment: @Gray_Rhino If we have 2 cashiers and 2 buyers (let's associate each cashier with number from 1 to 2 and each buyer with number from 1 to 2 just to differentiate them) then we will have such distributions: 1st cashier: 1st then 2nd buyer, 2nd cashier: nobody; 1st cashier: 2nd then 1st buyer, 2nd cashier nobody; 1st cashier: 1st buyer, 2nd cashier: 2nd buyer; 1st cashier: 2nd buyer, 2nd cashier: 1st buyer; 1st cashier: nobody, 2nd cashier: 1st buyer then 2nd buyer; 1st cashier: nobody, 2nd cashier: 2nd buyer then first buyer. Overall 6 different distributions. Order on each cashier matters.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I had such an idea but I don’t really know how to calculate number of ways of splitting n elements in k possibly empty groups. I have found some information about such a thing, it is pretty much the same as Stirling’s numbers of the second kind but they seem quite difficult to compute.

Comment: See my answer, then.  When posting questions, it's best if you put in everything you know, or have thought about the problem.  Then people can give you more relevant advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line all the customers up in a single line in $n!$ ways. Now we have to split them up into $k$ (possibly empty) groups and give the first group to the first cashier, the second to the second, and so on, so the question becomes, how many ways are there to split the line into $k$ groups?  Stars and bars gives the answer:$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}.$  The final answer is $$n!\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!}$$

Another way to see this is to add $k-1$ identical markers to the customers, and let each of the $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!}$ permutations of this multiset represent a distribution, where the markers indicate divisions between the lines.  Customers before the first marker go in the first line, customers between the first and second markers form the second line, and so on.